# Can you start a bounty on a question that already has an accepted answer?

Tags: support, bounty, accepted-answer

Can you start a bounty on a question that already has an accepted answer, if you feel that your answer to the question is better than the one that was accepted?

Comment: Of course you can!

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to, though. Could you expand your question to include your reasoning?

Comment: @AndrewLeach Some common reasons: to reward a user who posted an excellent answer (usually either the top-voted answer, the accepted answer, or the answer which is both, think eg of tchrist-style answers), to reward a user who posted an excellent answer which did not get the recognition you think it deserves (usually *not* the top answer or accepted answer), or to encourage renewed engagement with a question that everyone else considers settled (that is, *none* of the current answers completely satisfy you).

Comment: I mean especially when an 'old' and settled question does not satisfy you at all. ('Roundabouts and swings' on ELU, for example)

Comment: @user58319 Yes, that is one of the primary uses of bounties.

Comment: Related question, [Can I award a bounty to an answer given *before* the bounty? AND Can I divide a bounty between two or more answers?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4048/can-i-award-a-bounty-to-an-answer-given-before-the-bounty-and-can-i-divide-a).

Comment: @user58319 Yes, but when the best answer is *your own* answer, then why set a bounty? That's the question I meant, following from your post.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. Do note that the minimum bounty will be 100 reputation points (since you've already posted an answer to the question) and you can never award the bounty to your own answer.

Everything you want to know should be covered by the FAQ entry [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/295232) on Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: If I understand the OP correctly, in some sense the answer is then 'no', because they want to know if their -own- answer can get the bounty and if they themselves start the bounty, they can't then award it to themselves.